# Google Spreadsheet Script Trim First X Characters Each Cell in Range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet containing a column that looks like this:

1 - Apples
2 - Oranges
3 - Bananas
7 - Pineapples
2 - Oranges
1 - Apples
9 - Cherries
...

I am trying to write a script that trims the first 4 characters from each string leaving only remaining "fruit" substring.

Comment: var a ="1 - Apples"  var fruit = a.split(" - ")[1]

Comment: If you're sure that it's only 4 characters (as you said) `var fruit = a.substr(4);` is better than `split`. If not, then this is probably better: `fruit = a.substr(a.indexOf('-')+2);`. Because `split` will search the whole string and also split dashes (wrapped in spaces) in the names, if you have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the bellow pice of code. Adapt it to work with spreadsheets.

```
function myFunction() {
  var column = ["1 - Apples",
    "2 - Oranges",
    "3 - Bananas",
    "7 - Pineapples",
    "2 - Oranges",
    "1 - Apples",
    "9 - Cherries"];

  for(var x in column) {
    column[x] = column[x].substring(4);
    //or
    //column[x] =  column[x].split(" - ")[1]
  }

  Logger.log(column);
}
```

live version [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1ccWOL7AdSleFsjJud2umwWOQxQIvZXrNUZImWlLZ7fd6yfNYRaOwxyB6/edit?template=default&folder=0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U&usp=drive_web).

Comment: There's no need to specify `column[x].length`. If this parameter is omitted it considers the end of the string anyway.

Comment: This will stop working with number > 9... too bad :)

Comment: You are right Serge, let's start using regex :) 
But, if he use Hexadecimal it will not fail until F hahah